# Querying posts based off a jquery datepicker

Tags: php, wp-query, jquery

I have two jquery date pickers that i'm trying to filter post with. I store the jquery date picker values into a hidden input. Then i'm grabbing them with a php $_POST[]. I'm using meta_query to query those values but its not working Here's the code:

```
<label>Date From</label>
<input class="input-text date-picker" type="date" name="Date From" id="filter-date-range-from" value=""/><br>
<input type="hidden" id="from" name="from_input" value="">  

<label>Date To</label>
<input class="input-text date-picker" type="date" name="Date To" id="filter-date-range-to" value=""/><br>
<input type="hidden" id="to" name="to_input" value="">

<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

           var from = $("#filter-date-range-from").val();

           $("#from").val(from);

           //alert(from);
           var to = $("#filter-date-range-to").val();

           $("#to").val(to);
           //alert(to);

        });                     
</script>

<?php 
    $from   =  $_POST['from_input'];
    $to     = $_POST['to_input'];
    $args   = array(
    'post_type' => 'cases',   
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'meta_query' => array(
          'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'Start Date',
            'value' => $from,
            'compare' => '>='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'End Date',
            'value' => $to,
            'compare' => '<='
        )
      ) ,
    );
?>
```

Comment: Not working how? What are the results? Are `$from` and `$to` populated correctly? What is your date format?

Comment: Nothing shows. The results are nothing. If I remove the 'meta_query' all the posts show. When I echo $to and $form they both have dates. I tried a lot of different date formats.

Comment: Right now my date format is 'mmmm dd, yyyy'

Comment: your format has to be yyyy-mm-dd. they're just numbers, to order correctly they have to order naturally as numbers, and be compared as numbers.